# Focus on TextBox after ListView 'SelectionChanged' Event

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, focus

I wish to set focus on a `TextBox` after an item is selected from a `ListView` control, but I can't seem to get it to focus from within my 'SelectionChanged' event method `FocusOnTextBox()`.

For some reason the `ListView` always has focus after a selection is made.

**I have created a Visual Studio application to demonstrate this problem:**

http://maq.co/focusapp.zip

How can I get the focus to return to the `TextBox` from within my 'SelectionChanged' event method?

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView Name="list_view1" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="FocusOnTextBox">
            <ListViewItem Content="1" />
            <ListViewItem Content="2" />
            <ListViewItem Content="3" />
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Name="text_box1" Grid.Column="1" Text="When a selection is chosen from the left hand side ListView, I want THIS word to be selected and for the focus to change to this text box - this will show the selection to the user.&#x0a;&#x0a;However, right now it doesn't seem to work, the focus remains on the ListView regardless of it being set to Focus() in the FocusOnTextBox() method, which is fired on the 'SelectionChanged' event." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Test that the selection of the word THIS and the Focus() works
            text_box1.SelectionStart = 68;
            text_box1.SelectionLength = 4;

            text_box1.Focus();
        }

        private void FocusOnTextBox(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FocusOnTextBox fired on selection with list view");

            text_box1.SelectionStart = 68;
            text_box1.SelectionLength = 4;

            text_box1.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this happens because the `ListView` is not finished changing the selection, and so you switching focus from within the `SelectionChanged` event handler doesn't stick because after you've changed focus, the `ListView` changes it back in order to complete its selection change flow.

If you put a breakpoint in the `FocusOnTextBox` function and look at the Call Stack, you'll see that you're pretty deep into the stack, and there is a lot that the `ListView` will do after your `FocusOnTextBox` function executes.  I imagine one of the things it will do is set focus to the selected item in the `ListView`.

If you change it so that you're shifting focus after the `ListView` has completed changing the current selection, it should work.  For example, changing it so you switch focus in the `MouseLeftButtonUp` seems to work:

```
<ListView Name="list_view1" Grid.Column="0" MouseLeftButtonUp="FocusOnTextBox">
    <ListViewItem Content="1" />
    <ListViewItem Content="2" />
    <ListViewItem Content="3" />
</ListView>
```

And then you'll need to change the `FocusOnTextBox` event handler definition to use `MouseEventArgs` rather than `SelectionChangedEventArgs` as well.

Comment: +1 Nice! This is exactly it, I was just fiddling with it locally and could not get it to set focus on the SelectionChanged event; there is also no way to cancel the event and no event preview; your solution is elegant in that you attach the focus change to the end of the internal list-view event firing order when a user clicks to change a selection. As I was fiddling with this, I checked your solution and it does indeed work very nicely!

Comment: Thanks @DavidKhaykin.  I have wrestled a lot with Focus in WPF and it can get really hairy.  Even knowing why in this case, I was struggling with how to explain it clearly, so hopefully it makes sense.